# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, exception, insert

Hi 
i am trying to create an insertion form in ASP.net.
but i get this exception and i could not find this with google.

what am i doing wrong  ?

here is my code:

```
<div id = "survey_div">
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:surveyConnectionString1 %>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM survey" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO survey(age, country, city) VALUES (,,)" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT FROM survey" UpdateCommand="UPDATE survey SET">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="125px">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#DEE8F5" Font-Bold="True" />
    <Fields>
        <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
    </Fields>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
</asp:DetailsView>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's your `SelectCommand`, you need to either have a list of columns, or `*` between `Select` and `From` (preferably a list of columns).

Comment: yes that was that , but this is odd cause the code was created by vs itself :p

Comment: there is no exception now , but i cant see the insertion form , why?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `SelectCommand` in your `SqlDataSource` is not specifying any columns to select:

```
SELECT FROM survey
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!